# Promotion T-Shirt Design

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

According to the current discussion about the promotion of this site there come up the idea of a t-shirt with advertisement.

I want to collect some design ideas of a promotion t-shirt.

**Edit:** On a regular basis I try to give some preview links of good ideas (measured by the number of votes). Everybody is encouraged to do this on its own (especially if her/his favored idea doesn't get the most votes).

**Edit2:** Sorry for the long absence. I'm still going to look for a good T-shirt design. There are a lot of good ideas but I think we can get better ones :)

Comment: Can you please separate the idea (T-Shirt) and one solution? I do not like one as much as the other, sadly.

Comment: Maybe in time for SoCG :)

Answer (score 11):

One possible element of the design could be a modified logo, something like this:

[image: moified logo]

(although I seem to have introduced a little white dot creating this, and it may not have enough resolution; you'd have to do it properly).

Comment: this works as well. the only problem is that color makes things cost more. Maybe use the greyscale meta version ?

Comment: I like it because it is small, but I wonder if it is a bit too cryptic alone. Another possibility might be something like: "?!cstheory.stackexchange.com", using the same style (here ?! represents the logo).

Comment: Actually, I think it is perfect to go on the left side of the chest (where you often see logos), and leave the rest of the front clean. Then put "Questions answered. In theory./n http:// cstheory.stackexchange.com" on the back (or even leave out the "http://").

Comment: How about having a "sky blue" t-shirt with this logo exactly in the middle of the chest. The logo's background is "sky blue", so it'll mix with the t-shirt, and you'll only see the letters, the automaton, and the squares.

Comment: It should definitely have the arrow $! \rightarrow ?$ we discussed back then.

Comment: Also, I doubt the block looks good on a shirt. It should be more "open", I guess.

Comment: [Here](http://bit.ly/ex5FP3) is a preview of Joe's _implementation_ idea with Peter's (grayscaled) logo on the chest.

Comment: I like this latest preview. it seems a little bare on the front though - not sure what would be the right thing to fill in.

Comment: I think this is my favorite if the front design gets a little bit more action :)

Comment: [Here](http://bit.ly/fCOfGs) is a design idea with a centered logo and a slogan "Do you have a question?" on the chest.

Comment: @Marc I'm not sure about having the blocks filled in (as in the logo). Maybe instead just have the outermost border lines?

Comment: T-shirt design is fun. [My humble attempt](http://www.cafepress.com/cp/customize/product2.aspx?number=548965629).

Answer (score 9):

I'd ditch the "researched question" and "researched answer" text and merely use "Questions answered. In theory."

Comment: I'd keep it as simple and neutral as possible. Maybe just something like the text "Questions answered. In theory." + URL "cstheory.stackexchange.com", in a not-too-large font, without any logos.

Comment: Here is a possible realization with logo http://bit.ly/fvYdWw . I think a logo is good to identifiy this page and should be on the shirt (perhaps in some modified version).

Comment: @Marc Gillé, it is nice. :) btw, I think it would be better for promotion if the web address of the cstheory is recognizable from distance.

Comment: another idea is to frame the logo with 'Questions Answered' on top, and 'In theory' below.

Comment: URL and nodes are too small. And I miss the backarrow! ;) The catchphrase is awesome, though.

Answer (score 8):

upd. Here is a simple picture: [image]
upd2. A couple more pictures, as suggested by Dave Clarke:
[image]
[image]

<strike>Let me suggest a complexity-oriented slogan: "CSTheory -- we prove that $Researcher \subsetneq Researcher^{Community}$". I can try to make a picture with "Researcher" replaced by a picture of one guy and "Community" by a picture of a bunch of guys or something along these lines, if somebody likes this idea.</strike>

Comment: that is so geeky I am impressed :)

Comment: Nice. I'd drop the "we prove that", perhaps replacing it by "where" or just leaving it out all together.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I uploaded these two versions above.

Comment: wow ! geeky to the max. I'm scared when I even think of how I'd explain this to someone :)

Comment: Really nice job! I want one (the one without text). :D

Comment: I really like the right hand side, but it seems to clash a bit with the logo. I think just the right hand side + Suresh's slogan would be a good clean design.

Comment: pretty cool :) would've liked this on my tshirt

Answer (score 5):

A less design related proposal: In the context of DIY shops like spreadshirt and the like, is it possible to write a script that allows users to hit "This question on your shirt!" and forwards them to a shop's shirt designer with our default design and their favorite question title preset? Call it RL-tweet.

That would allow for a more individual experience with a common theme. A given question might also attract others more than the site name (alone).

You can also think of variations like "[QUESTION]? Answered." vs "[QUESTION]? Open."

Comment: Interesting idea. don't know if there are any shops that do this though.

Comment: If you substitute the "Questions answered. In theory." text on the shirt with the favorite question (and "Answered" or "Open" tag), it isn't complicated to do it on your own (assuming that there is a template where the rest of the shirt is fixed). I think your idea is a good way to give a short insight of the kind of questions asked here and to personalize the shirts.

Answer (score 3):

Apparantly, there are efforts to create promotion goodies for all Stackexchange sites: [Blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/supporting-community-conferences/). Maybe we will soon be represented there, too.

Answer (score 2):

I start with this one

[Front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2BJ2.png)
[Back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLtsK.png)

On a real t-shirt it looks like

[Cafepress.com](http://bit.ly/g1BCc0)

---

Thanks to Suresh for the tikz example.

Comment: That's a cool design!