# Promotion T-shirt Implementation

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Is there any chance that some ideas from [this discussion](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/promotion-t-shirt-design) might be implemented some day?

If yes, probably, we can start discussion here?

Comment: I don't think a separate discussion is necessary.

Comment: @chazisop The idea was to get more attention, because that discussion was started long time ago.

Comment: @Dori: Can we combine the plans with the [promotion event at FCRC](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1045/promoting-tcs-se-at-fcrc) (June 4 - 11)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my mind, here's how this would work:

1. we decide a design or two
2. We set up a design on cafepress or somewhere similar
3. We investigate with our SE overlords if they might be willing to sponsor purchasing some of said T-shirts
4. We have volunteers at FCRC wearing these T-shirts and doing site promotion.

3': We advertise links to the cafepress site so people can buy their own if they like.

Comment: Thank you, sounds good. However, I am not sure about 3. Are you sure they would be interested?

Of course, I personally would be happy to purchase such T-shirt just on my own and to wear it at FCRC. Hopefully, there are other volunteers too :)

Comment: ad 2: Take care choosing a proper store. I know, for instance, that a store on spreadshirt.com is not accessible on spreadshirt.net (and vice versa), shutting out European customers from NA vendors (and vice versa).