# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sponsorship

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the cstheory community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant Computer Science conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free talk about anything he or she wants so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site -- with a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: The big event of this year is [FCRC](http://www.acm.org/fcrc/). (should we add the `featured` tag?)

Comment: This might also be useful: http://www.confsearch.org/confsearch/faces/pages/topic.jsp?topic=Theory&sortMode=1&graphicView=1

Comment: @Jeff: As you mention calls for papers, are you suggesting that someone would actually submit a paper that promotes the cstheory web site to a major TCS conference, get the paper accepted, and then go to the conference and give a talk on this web site? [I don't see how this could possibly happen...] Or are you interested in sponsoring *any* talk at a major conference from a member of the community? Or any talk as long as the talk briefly mentions cstheory?

Comment: I'm giving an invited presentation at a relatively small event, the PACO workshop (http://www.win.tue.nl/paco2011/) associated with the DiscoTec federated conference. I will certainly plug cstheory.SE. I don't need any sponsorship, as I'm going to the conference anyway.

Comment: Do some of you have promotion slides you would be willing to share? I attended a (small, rather local) workshop today and scold myself in retrospect for not taking the opportunity. Was there a "consensus" set of promotion materials, spontaneous promotion might be promoted.

Comment: @Raphael: what kinds of material do you think would be handy ?

Comment: A flashy description, some (three?) great (open?) questions and some (three?) solved questions with very good answers. Names of famous people who are here, statements about cstheory of such or what people say they get out of cstheory (we have a thread for that).

Comment: Btw, I think submission to STOC's poster session is still open.

Comment: @Raphael: Currently I have a slide that says "Plug cstheory here". I'm not yet prepared, but I'd happily use and existing material or share the slide(s) I ultimately use.

Comment: based on Jeff's most recent edit, I'd say that FCRC is the way to go: I don't know who among us are going, but possible sponsored speakers could include David Eppstein, Ryan Williams and Peter Shor (if we're looking for well known people)

Comment: @Suresh: Sounds like a good idea. Maybe you could post this suggestion as another answer, and then people can more easily edit and comment on it.

Comment: I am definitely going to FCRC, and I'll be giving a conference talk there. I am not sure how much this information aligns with the request above.

Answer (score 12):

As Kaveh points out, the most bang for the buck is at the FCRC, which combines a large number of ACM conferences, and can also serve as advertisement for creating SE sites in other research domains.

There are many people here who are probably already going to FCRC and might have papers at STOC/CCC/EC (I'm not one of them unfortunately - I'm going to a different conference at the same time).

However, all these conferences are well past their deadlines for paper submission and the program is probably mostly set. Also, these conferences don't usually have slots for promotional discussions. Possibly one good place to advertise this site would be at the STOC business meeting, where a discussion item could be placed on the agenda (and I can help with contacting the relevant people).

There's even been talk of [printing cstheory T-shirts](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/promotion-t-shirt-design), although that effort is languishing a little.

I've been busy with work and haven't had time to think about promotional efforts lately, but I'd be willing to help out in any way I can.

The next big conference after FCRC, whose program has NOT been set yet, is [FOCS 2011](http://www.cs.ucla.edu/~rafail/FOCS11/)

p.s Jeff, one of the MOST effective ways we could have done promotion would have been with a formal SIGACT tie-in (SIGACT runs the major theory conference happening at FCRC), but ever since Joel's post on a federated CS stackexchange, that has bee dormant (inspite my repeated queries).

Answer (score 4):

*(converted from a comment as per request)*

Based on Jeff's most recent edit, I'd say that FCRC is the way to go: I don't know who among us are going, but possible sponsored speakers could include David Eppstein, Ryan Williams and Peter Shor (if we're looking for well known people). Just to clarify, I'm not implying that there aren't other well known people here (hi Luca!). I'm merely optimizing for SE activity AND external profile.

Comment: Yes, FCRC really would be the way to go. What's the status of all this? There isn't too much time left...

Comment: I don't know. Is Jeff around ?

Comment: can you email rcartaino@stackoverflow.com with details and timeline?

Answer (score 3):

The next meeting is not until January 2012, but [Science Online](http://scienceonline2011.com/about/) is a good fit for cstheory, and other science-related StackExchange sites.

Comment: yes, that could be an interesting place.